# Reference Dyanmic JSON Key Prefix in Node

Tags: node.js, json

I have a connection string where I want to reference a dynamic password variable that changes based on environment.  I've set this prefix as part of my script so it exists as variable `environment` in my config list.  But when I attempt to use it in JSON path, I'm only getting the key back, not the value.

String variable:

```
  const mongoUri = `mongodb+srv://` + config.env.mongoUser + `:${config.env.environment}MongoPassword`;
```

config output:

```
config: {
  env: {
    mongoUser: 'company-user-dev',
    environment: 'dev',
    devMongoPassword: 'xxxxxxx'
  }
}
```

Console output:
`MONGO URI mongodb+srv://company-user-dev:devMongoPassword`

Looking for:
`MONGO URI mongodb+srv://company-user-dev:xxxxxx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the key- `devMongoPassword`, Now all you need to do is get the value of this key from the config.

```
config.env[`${config.env.environment}MongoPassword`]
```

```js
const config = {
  env: {
    mongoUser: 'company-user-dev',
    environment: 'dev',
    devMongoPassword: 'xxxxxxx'
  }
}

console.log(`mongodb+srv://` + config.env.mongoUser + ':' + config.env[`${config.env.environment}MongoPassword`]);
```